# Video On/Off Button is not showing in Vonage Video API

Tags: javascript, webrtc, opentok, tokbox, vonage

I am working on a video conference solution which involves one-to-one video call (doctor-patient), To implement webRTC I am using vonage api solution, I have tried their embed video call solution which is perfect as it provides video on/off features, But using embed we cannot archive the conversation,hence i am now using vonage api.

I have working solution which includes features like one-to-one video call and archiving videos automatically to s3 bucket, Although i can see small button for audio on/off, I am not able to see the button for video on/off like embed video chat, i have also tried to on/off the video manually using the documentation as on the link - [vonage docs](https://tokbox.com/developer/guides/audio-video/js/#publish_audio_video_only) But still i am not able to disable/enable videos manually, sometimes it works on safari though. So can anyone help me with this ?

```
<script src="https://static.opentok.com/v2/js/opentok.min.js"></script>

var session = OT.initSession(apiKey, sessionId);
session.on('streamCreated', function(event) {
       session.subscribe(event.stream, 'subscriber', {
         insertMode: 'append',
         width: '100%',
         height: '100%'
       }, handleError);
     });
     
   var publisher = OT.initPublisher('publisher', {
     insertMode: 'append',
     width: '100%',
     height: '100%'
   }, handleError);
```

I am using above code to facilitate one-to-one video call, and tried setting video on/off functionality by using below code, But it is not working,

```
var pubOptions = {publishAudio:true, publishVideo:false};
var publisher = OT.initPublisher('publisher', pubOptions, {
     insertMode: 'append',
     width: '100%',
     height: '100%'
   }, handleError);
   
var options = {subscribeToAudio:true, subscribeToVideo:false};
session.on('streamCreated', function(event) {
       session.subscribe(event.stream, options,'subscriber', {
         insertMode: 'append',
         width: '100%',
         height: '100%'
       }, handleError);
     });
```

Any help will be appreciated, Thanks and cheers..!

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for the `publishAudio` and `publishVideo` methods on the publisher object.

Both accept a boolean denoting whether to publish that content. So using something like below would cause the [publisher](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/js/reference/Publisher.html#methods) to stop sharing their video:

```js
var publisher = OT.initPublisher('publisher', pubOptions, {
     insertMode: 'append',
     width: '100%',
     height: '100%'
   }, handleError);

publisher.publishVideo(false);
```

If you're trying to mute the audio/video coming from someone else, you'll use the `subscribeToAudio` and `subscribeToVideo` methods on the [subscriber](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/js/reference/Subscriber.html#methods) object. Both also accept booleans. This would mean you need to keep track of your subscribers.

```js
session.on('streamCreated', function(event) {
  const subscriber = session.subscribe(event.stream, options,'subscriber', {
    insertMode: 'append',
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%'
    }, handleError);
  subscriber.subscribeToVideo(false);
});
```

You may want to look at the [OpenTok Accelerators](https://www.npmjs.com/package/opentok-accelerator-core). They provide a lot of functionality already baked in, including state.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this but video icon is not displaying on the subscriber video.